# Ubuntu on USB does not boot on MacBook

Tags: 11.10, usb, macbook, windows-xp, dual-boot

Ubuntu is installed on a 32 gigabyte flash-drive and it successfully booted every time up until I partitioned my hard-drive and installed Windows as a secondary boot (for programming reasons). 
Now every time I attempt to boot the Ubuntu flash-drive it boots into Windows XP. The same goes for partitions, I partitioned my hard-drive and installed Ubuntu and it only booted Windows XP.

I am on a MacBook 6,1 with Mac OS X 10.6.8, 2 partitions, and I am using ReFit as my boot-loader.

EDIT: I had Ubuntu working fine from FLASH DRIVE and at one point as a partition. I later uninstalled Ubuntu from my hard-drive and installed Windows. I then had to re-image my computer for certain reasons and I installed windows. Now when I attempt to boot anything other than Windows or OS X it boots into windows.

Ubuntu was never on my hard drive while Ubuntu was on it. The flash-drive has been its own thing and has the boot-loader installed to it and loads from ReFit but boots into windows.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you have overwritten the GRUB boot loader with the Windows one.

Comment: Windows was installed first.

Comment: @SeanH you should rewrite your question then.  It describes how you had no problem with Ubuntu *until* you installed Windows.  You'll get better answers once you clarify how you got the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are articles that may help you:

- http://fosswire.com/post/2009/05/restoring-overwritten-grub/
- http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub.html
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Grub2
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GrubHowto/ChangeDefaultOS